# Using URIs with HTTP POST

Tags: c#, wcf

Is it possible to use URIs that are visible in the address bar of a browser with methods that use HTTP POST? For example, I have an `OperationContract` defined like this:

```
[OperationContract, WebInvoke(Method = "POST")]
Stream GetFile(string username, int fileid);
```

At the moment, both parameters are sent using POST. However, what if I only wanted to send 'username' by POST and have 'fileid' visible in the URI? Would the following work?

```
[OperationContract, WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "GetFile?fileid={fileid}")]
Stream GetFile(string username, int fileid);
```

i.e., I want `GetFile?fileid={fileid}` visible in the address bar of the browser accessing the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it could work.  Certainly HTTP POST requests can have query parameters.